# How can i find work item in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

How can i find work item in TFS
I know only part word in title

exampe

WorkItem
Title ='Best task **abra**kadabra'

I need find '**abra**'

In mssql i'm use LIKE '**%abra%**'

Tell me please how make this in Team Foundation Server

Thanks

Comment: Can't use just run a query in the workitems interface? Title Contains abra?

Comment: Please explain how you want this: as a user using the Web interface? In a .Net program using the Client Model API? In a script? Against which TFS version?
Questions too generic risk being closed without answers.

Comment: Im use web interface. TFS latest version.

Answer (score 0):

There is Contains Operator in Query, so you can create a query like this:

Work Item Type       =         Task

And Title          Contains    abra